# symfony routing.yml config for site folders

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have symfony web files in web root folder where the project is running. I have site files such as index.html, aboutus.html and contactus.html files. I have put these files into public_html/site/ How to access these files by default using routing.yml? also project should run in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Hm...If you want to add to your project some static pages, I would recommend you **[this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowtoServeStaticContent)** method.I think this is the right way.  For index.php ,well read **[this](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01)**

Comment: No. It will not help me. I have static pages in html. That should not be mingle with project files such as css and images. So I want to put these static pages into webroot/site/ and have to link default.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a new module for static pages and move the html content into it?
You have to understand that routing system in symfony is used for connect requested urls to controllers. So you can't use it to provide generating urls for static pages outside of your symfony application. That files are just like files of foreign site.
So you can just use link_to('about us', $this->getRequest()->getHost().'/about_us.html');